# Receiving NoMethodError in Follows#followers when paginate_array is empty in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, kaminari

I'm currently trying to list all users that the current user is following/being followed by. I managed to get some functionality working by wrapping the current_user.all_following method in a Kaminari.paginate_array function. Which is for controlling the amount of users that are being pulled from the database. Since acts_as_follower is using arrays, I cannot take the traditional approach of just iterating over the object itself and grabbing each record that is following/being followed. My code is simple, because there isn't much that needs to be done. How can I fix the NoMethodError in my view? Disclaimer: **@users = Kaminari.paginate_array(current_user.all_following(order: "follows.follower_id DESC")).page(params[:page]).per(26)** works when the array is populated, but fails when the array has no entries. current_user.all_follows fails the same way.

rails console

```
> @user.all_follows(order: "created_at DESC")
  Follow Load (34.0ms)  SELECT  "follows".* FROM "follows" WHERE "follows"."follower_id" = $1 AND "follows"."follower_type" = $2 AND "follows"."blocked" = $3 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT $4  [["follower_id", 2], ["follower_type", "User"], ["blocked", "f"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
missed ids -> 1 | hitted ids -> 
  User Load (15.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1
#<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Follow id: 1, followable_type: "User", followable_id: 1, follower_type: "User", follower_id: 2, blocked: false, created_at: "2018-02-26 00:42:28", updated_at: "2018-02-26 00:42:28">]>
```

follows_controller.rb

```
class FollowsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def following
    @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(current_user.all_following(order: "follows.follower_id DESC")).page(params[:page]).per(26)
  end

  def followers
    @users = Kaminari.paginate_array(current_user.all_follows(order: "follows.id DESC")).page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end
end
```

followers.html.erb

```
<h1>People following me</h1>
<% @users.each do |user| %>
    <div class="media">
      <%= user_avatar_following(user) %>
      <div class="media-body">
        <h6 class="mt-0 mb-1"><%= fa_icon 'user-o' %><strong> <%= link_to user.username, user %></strong></h6>
        <%= fa_icon 'map-marker', style: 'color: orange;' %> <%= user.state %>
        <div class="cool-ppl-to-follow-btn-pos">
          <div id="follow_user<%=user.id%>">
            <% unless user == current_user %>
              <% if current_user.following?(user) %>
                <%= link_to(unfollow_user_path(user), :remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-outline-danger') do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-stop-circle"></i>
                  Unfollow
                <% end %>
              <% else %>
                <%= link_to(follow_user_path(user) ,:remote => true, :class => 'btn btn-outline-primary') do %>
                  <i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i>
                  Follow
                <%end%>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

following.html.erb code is the same

route.rb

```
controller :follows  do
    get 'follows/following', as: 'following'
    get 'follows/followers', as: 'followers'
  end
```

follows_helper.rb

```
module FollowsHelper

      def user_avatar_following(current_user)
          if current_user.user_profile.avatar.url.present?
            image_tag current_user.user_profile.avatar.feed_thumb, class: 'd-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail'
          else
            inline_svg 'follow_assets/add-user-avatar.svg', size: '12% * 12%', class: 'd-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail'
          end
        end
    end
```

error

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `user_profile' for #<Follow:0x0000000011d98288>):
    1: <h1>People following me</h1>
    2: <% @users.each do |user| %>
    3:     <div class="media">
    4:       <%= user_avatar_following(user) %>
    5:       <div class="media-body">
    6:         <h6 class="mt-0 mb-1"><%= fa_icon 'user-o' %><strong> <%= link_to user.username, user %></strong></h6>
    7:         <%= fa_icon 'map-marker', style: 'color: orange;' %> <%= user.state %>

app/helpers/follows_helper.rb:3:in `user_avatar_following'
app/views/follows/followers.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_follows_followers_html_erb__245299866_149493120'
app/views/follows/followers.html.erb:2:in `each'
app/views/follows/followers.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_follows_followers_html_erb__245299866_149493120'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:34:in `activate_account_time_zone'
```

Comment: Which error are you trying to fix? the one in the heading of your question, or the one in the body of your question?

Comment: I updated the body to focus on the error itself. Since, its causing the problems for me. This is the first time that I had this issue w/acts_as_follower. Normally, the users would populate the view without issue.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by changing the code in my **following** method to:

```
@followers = Kaminari.paginate_array(current_user.followers).page(params[:page]).per(25)
```

Now, its working like it should.

Comment: Yeah I was going to say... you've got a variable called `@users` but actually it's being populated by follows... but because it's named `@users`, you were treating it as though it actually contains users... and the `follow` wasn't repsonding to the `user` method `user_profile`